# Video element events not firing in Next.js project

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, next.js

In a Next.js project I am trying to include a video that, when loaded, calls a function. However it seems that the [`onLoadedData`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onloadeddata.asp) event does not fire.

I tried a number of other HTMLVideoElement events such as `onLoadStart` and `onCanPlay` and none of them seem to fire as expected.

I tested this on a native React application and had no issues, so the problem seems to be specific to Next and possibly SSR related.

Looking at other posts, it looks like a possible workaround is with [dynamic imports](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66490267/18336761), but I'm ultimately looking to use a video imported from a third-party library and if possible would like to avoid adding the bulk of [having to make a wrapper component to handle the video](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66842797/18336761).

Here is the code where the `onLoadedData` event does not fire, within my `page.tsx`:

```
'use client';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <video src="videos/my-video.mp4" onLoadedData={() => console.log('loaded')} />
  );
}
```